# How to close error reporting to Ubuntu

Tags: release-loki, settings, system

When I turning UFW on, it blocks the all ports and a log is occurred about this action:

`whoopsie[607]: [11:39:36] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com`

Ubuntu help page says that:

> Ubuntu error tracker submission This program submits crash reports to
>   an Ubuntu server. It makes a DNS query for daisy.ubuntu.com on every
>   boot. To disable:
>
> (Warning: Ubuntu will lose ability to report bugs)
>
> Click the icon at the far right of the menu bar and select System
>   Settings.  Open Security & Privacy and select the Diagnostics tab.
>
> Switch off "Send error reports to Canonical".  Log out and log back in
>   for the change to take effect.

So I wonder how can I switch off "Send error reports to Canonical" option on Elementary OS Loki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove whoopsie (from the command line):

```
sudo apt remove --purge whoopsie
```